# Android open url in my browser

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

By clicking on the link opens a default browser, whether it is possible to make so that when clicked opened my application - browser, if it is installed, if not then open a default browser?
my code:

```
   String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
   if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) url = "http://" +   url;
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
   context.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to have scheme defined in your manifest for example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyMainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="myapp" /> <!-- see this -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Add following in the `Activity`

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    // Handle intent extras
}
```

The link in web-browser would be like: **myapp:open_url=http://www.google.fi**

Then you parse the url from `Intent` extras and open it in `WebView`

Here is also interesting post: http://danielmuller.asia/2013/02/android-open-an-app-from-web-link-or-fallback-to-market/

Answer (score 0):

You should integrate app deep linking in your android app, in order to open your app by clicking link from browser

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2014/06/android-app-indexing-is-now-open-for.html

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/app?utm_source=wmc-blog&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=apps-for-all